# Is "pain" a noun or a verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns

For example, which of the following sentences is correct:

> 1. My eyes are paining.
> 2. There is a pain in my eyes.

Comment: If you are looking for a verb, you might wish to use ["hurt"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hurt) instead. "My eyes are hurting."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sentence 2 is correct: "there is a pain in my eyes".

Pain can be a noun or verb, for example:

> The pain is terrible = noun
>
> It pains me to see you this way = verb

For more details please see:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pain

Comment: If the pain is both Noun an Verb both the sentence should be correct?

Comment: Yup, Pain is a transitive verb.

Comment: It is paining me to see you like this ;)

Comment: @Amitabh The intransitive use of "to pain" - "My eyes are paining" - is not used in current English.